# How to implement doIndex method from Jenkins RootAction class

Tags: java, jenkins

I create my own implementation of RootAction in Jenkins, instead of default behavior that just render and display index.jelly, I want to do some operations. as states from http://stapler.kohsuke.org/reference.html

Index Action Method
This is a slight variation of above. If there's no remaining URL and there's an action method called "doIndex", this method will be invoked. Formally, 
evaluate(node,[]) := node.doIndex(...)

my code is

```html
@Extension
public class MyRootAction implements RootAction {
   public void doIndex(StaplerRequest req, StaplerResponse rsp) {
        // doing my work when user type /MyRootAction in browser bar
        // this method never executed
   }

   public void doOtherWork(StaplerRequest req, StaplerResponse rsp) {
        // doing my work when user type /MyRootAction/otherWork in browser bar
        // this method works as intended
   }
   //...
}
```

Any one can help me to point what I did wrong?

Comment: I found the reason. The index.jelly file is present for this action. Renaming index.jelly would allow doIndex to be executed